# AWS Go SDK credential discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk, aws-sdk-go

I'm working with AWS, and usually I write programs in Python with the `boto3` / `botocore` libraries if I want to automate something. Now I'm trying to learn Golang, but one thing I found strange is how the AWS SDK for Go handles a possible chain in credentials.

For example, the `botocore` library is super simple to use for an authentication source; in fact, I don't have to worry about "discovering" AWS credentials because `botocore` handles that automatically. Turning on the debug logs for any particular Python scripts reveals the following:

```
2020-09-11 20:32:59 my-local-machine botocore.credentials[91719] DEBUG Looking for credentials via: env
2020-09-11 20:32:59 my-local-machine botocore.credentials[91719] DEBUG Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2020-09-11 20:32:59 my-local-machine botocore.credentials[91719] DEBUG Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2020-09-11 20:32:59 my-local-machine botocore.credentials[91719] DEBUG Looking for credentials via: sso
2020-09-11 20:32:59 my-local-machine botocore.credentials[91719] DEBUG Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2020-09-11 20:32:59 my-local-machine botocore.credentials[91719] INFO Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
```

As you can see, it goes through each possibility until it discovers a viable option; in this case, my local `~/.aws/credentials` file.

I think a similar type of easy credentials discovery doesn't exist in Go from what I've seen.

- Is this true, and why?
- Also, what is a good example of existing Golang code where multiple types of credentials can be "discovered" automatically?

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials#ChainProvider

Comment: @Peter does this mean that the discovery process is something you have to specify manually? Seems very unlike Python's approach, which is to just let `botocore` determine which authentication source should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK for Go uses a similar scheme. As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials):

> When you initialize a new service client without providing any credential arguments, the SDK uses the [default credential provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/defaults/#CredChain) to find AWS credentials. The SDK uses the first provider in the chain that returns credentials without an error. The default provider chain looks for credentials in the following order:
>
> 1. Environment variables.
> 2. Shared credentials file.
> 3. If your application uses an ECS task definition or RunTask API operation, IAM role for tasks.
> 4. If your application is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, IAM role for Amazon EC2.
>
> The SDK detects and uses the built-in providers automatically, without
> requiring manual configurations

For the V1 version (whose document is linked), you would create a session and that's it. For the V2 version (currently under development), you would use `external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()` after importing the package `"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"`